# Converting GMT date to local time zone date - flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, datetime, gmt

I am getting GMT date from api response:

**Thu, 13 Oct 2022 00:09:35 GMT**

Using below code to convert it to local date :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("Thu, 13 Oct 2022 00:09:35 GMT");
print("converted gmt date >> " + dt.toString());
final _localTime = dt.toLocal();
print("local modified date >> "+_localTime.toString());
```

But Getting below error :

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format
> E/flutter ( 3323): Thu, 13 Oct 2022 00:09:35 GMT
> E/flutter ( 3323): #0      DateTime.parse (dart:core/date_time.dart:347:7)
> E/flutter ( 3323): #1      HomeProvider.fetchModifiedDate. (package:mahotsav/src/framework/dataProvider/Home/homeProvider.dart:1677:32)
> E/flutter ( 3323): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
> E/flutter ( 3323): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
> E/flutter ( 3323):

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` expects time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. If you change your format before parsing, it should convert it successfully.